# Как в C++ считать с textBox формулу?

Tags: c++

Как без напряга можно считать формулу, желательно с поддержкой дужек и тригонометричесских функций. Может у кого-то есть готовые функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть различные библиотеки, которые позволяют считать математические выражения в C++, например:

- [Mathematical Expression Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html),
- [Mathematical Expression Parser](http://code.google.com/p/muparserx/).

Также в библиотеке Boost Spirit есть примеры, по созданию математических парсеров.

Comment: к сожалению на моем visual studio 2010 не работает или я что то не так сделал )) но все равно спасибо за ответ ))

Answer (score 1):

flex/bison , написать парсер выражений в AST-дерево, или вычислять прямо в процессе разбора (классический syntax driven интерпретатор, без байт-кода)

как вариант, использовать **атрибутные грамматики**, пример кода для yacc https://stackoverflow.com/a/42106966/2134384

обзорно основы атрибутных грамматик описаны в [ИТМО: Атрибутные транслирующие грамматики](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8)

основы lex/yacc я начинал осваивать отсюда: https://habrahabr.ru/post/99162/

если добавите к вопросу примеры выражений, набросаю лексер/парсер -- распознавание и **вычисление** мат.выражений делается достаточно элементарно, включая *встроенные* функции (sin, log, любые внешние библиотеки).

До тех пор, пока не захотите *пользовательские функции*. С этого момента вам придется переформулировать вопрос на "как реализовать свой язык программирования". Тогда придется лезть хотя бы в PLAI book: https://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/

ЗЫ: надеюсь не имеется в виду распознавание рукописных формул 8-)

Comment: решение с ручным разбором: https://habrahabr.ru/post/50139/

Comment: применение flex/bison подробно расписано в https://github.com/ponyatov/uc/releases/latest , пока только лексер (основы), позже добавлю парсер и прямую интерпретацию, как раз к теме вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Не дождавшись примеров выражений, вот пример парсера (текста много, поэтому ссылка): https://github.com/ponyatov/620500/tree/parser

Текст

```
# comment
A= -01++02.30*4e-5^(6.7E8/9)    # expression & var
sin(x)/cos(pi)                  # std.functions & const
.end                            # .end directive
all text here will be ignored
```

превращается в AST-дерево

```
************* src.src *************

<op:=> #0x2f1388
    <sym:A> #0x2f1338
    <op:+> #0x2f1468
        <op:-> #0x2f13d8
            <num:1> #0x2f1428
        <op:*> #0x2f3a78
            <op:+> #0x2f14b8
                <num:2.3> #0x2f1510
            <op:^> #0x2f3b10
                <num:4e-005> #0x2f3ad0
                <op:/> #0x2f80a0
                    <num:6.7e+008> #0x2f80c0
                    <num:9> #0x2f80e8
====================================

<op:/> #0x2f83d8
    <op:@> #0x2f83b8
        <sym:sin> #0x2f8140
        <sym:x> #0x2f1080
    <op:@> #0x2f8478
        <sym:cos> #0x2f83f8
        <sym:pi> #0x2f8438
====================================
```

Для узлов дерева используется набор так называемых *algebraic* классов, в качестве базового взято **представление любых данных в виде текста** в паре `<тэг:значение>`, с возможностью хранения вложенных элементов `vector<Sym> nest`, и атрибутов `map<string,Sym> attr`. Базовый класс `Sym` специально сделан виртуальным, чтобы можно было работать с экземплярами наследованных классов через указатели `Sym*`, в т.ч. хранить их в STL-контейнерах.

**Добавляем интерпретацию выражений**, и глобальную таблицу символов `env:global`:
https://github.com/ponyatov/620500/tree/eval

```
A= -01++02.30*4e-5^(6.7E-8/9)   # expression & var
```

превращается в (1) AST-дерево, которое вычисляется в (2) другое дерево-результат, и также выведено (3) состояние глобальной таблицы символов:

```
************* src.src *************

<op:=> #0x4b1578
    <sym:A> #0x4b12f8
    <op:+> #0x4b1628
        <op:-> #0x4b15b0
            <num:1> #0x4b15e8
        <op:*> #0x4b16f0
            <op:+> #0x4b1660
                <num:2.3> #0x4b1698
            <op:^> #0x4b1728
                <num:4e-005> #0x4b1ed8
                <op:/> #0x4b1798
                    <num:6.7e-008> #0x4b1f18
                    <num:9> #0x4b1f58
---------------------

<op:=> #0x4b1578
    <sym:A> #0x4b12f8
    <num:1.3> #0x668030
---------------------

<env:global> #0x41c020
    ABOUT =
        'simple flex/bison/c(++) calculator [interpreter sample]' #0x661328
    AUTHOR =
        'Dmitry Ponyatov <dponyatov@gmail.com>' #0x6613f8
    COPYRIGHT =
        <op:+> #0x662910
            DATE =
                <fn:date> #0x4b0c10
            '(c) ' #0x666ec0
            <sym:AUTHOR> #0x666f10
            <sym:LICENCE> #0x666f60
            <sym:DATE> #0x4b0bd8
    GITHUB =
        'https://github.com/ponyatov/620500/tree/eval' #0x661540
    LICENCE =
        'GNU LesserGPL' #0x6614b0
    MODULE =
        '620500' #0x661198
    TITLE =
        'calculator' #0x661248
    cos =
        <fn:cos> #0x4b1118
    pi =
        <num:3.14159> #0x4b0c68
    sin =
        <fn:sin> #0x4b10d8
====================================
```

В исходник добавлен пример *переключения входного потока лексера на разбор строковой переменной* -- это как раз важно для интерпретации TextInput полей, или интерпретации потока с сетевого сокета.

Можно также обратить внимание на `global/COPYRIGHT` -- пример зачаточной реализации пользовательских функций, создается в cpp.cpp/glob_init пообъектно, т.к. этот лексер определения функций не поддерживaет.

**TODO:**

1. есть большая проблема в sym.eval() - утечка памяти когда результат вычисленния заменяет старое значение. **нужно добавить автоматическое управление памятью**
2. определение пользовательских функций
3. ООП с переопределением операторов -- здорово улучшает читаемость кода при написании и использовании библиотек, например библиотека матричных операций
4. если очень хочется использовать в работе: все же необходим компилятор, скорее всего на базе LLVM JIT, чтобы можно было прямо в скриптах создавать обертки для объектов LLVM, и выполнять для них managed компиляцию в ОЗУ, как минимум для пользовательских функций

Comment: на python+PLY код попроще и красивее получается, и сборка мусора из коробки

Answer (score 0):

А если внешний куркулятор, например тот же bc?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int main() {
    char *s;
    char out[100];
    FILE *p = popen("echo \"sqrt(2+2)+l(6)\" | bc -l", "r");
    fgets(out, sizeof out, p);
    out[strlen(out)-1] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", out);
 }
```

Только там математические функции по-своему записываются. l -- логарифм.